# Angular not mapping JSON response to nested interfaces

Tags: json, angular, typescript

My JSON response (from ASP.NET core Web API) looks like:

```
[
  {
    "pilot": {
      "firstName": "TEST",
      "lastName": "LAST",
      "assignedFlight": "O_FLIGHT"
    }
  },
  {
    "pilot": {
      "firstName": "First",
      "lastName": "Last",
      "assignedFlight": "M_FLIGHT"
    }
  }
]
```

My TypeScript interfaces look like:

**pilot.ts**

```
export interface Pilot {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    assignedFlight: string;
}
```

**commitment.ts**

```
import { Pilot } from './pilot';

export interface Commitment {
    pilot: Pilot;
}
```

And in my **commitments.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommitmentsService {

  private commitmentsApiUrl = 'http://localhost:55012/commitments';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCommitments(): Observable<Commitment[]> {
    return this.http.get<Commitment[]>(this.commitmentsApiUrl).pipe(tap(ev => console.log(ev)));
  }
}
```

Finally, I subscribe to the observable in my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-commitments',
  templateUrl: './commitments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./commitments.component.css']
})
export class CommitmentsComponent implements OnInit {

  commitments: Commitment[];

  constructor(private commitmentsService: CommitmentsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.commitmentsService.getCommitments().subscribe(commitments => this.commitments = commitments);
    console.log(this.commitments); /* Undefined here??? */
  }
}
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why the JSON is not being mapped when a nested interface is involved. `this.commitments` in the component shows `undefined`. I've run the JSON through a JSON validator/linter and it shows that it's valid. I know the answer is something simple that I am over-looking. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: return this.http.get<Commitment[]>(this.commitmentsApiUrl).toPromise() ; in @Component: this.commitmentsService.getCommitments().then().catch() or async/await.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface looks fine. `this.commitments` is assigned asynchronously. By the time you do console log, the variable `this.commitments` is still undefined. You need to move the `console.log()` inside the subscription.

```js
this.commitmentsService.getCommitments().subscribe(
  commitments => {
    this.commitments = commitments;
    console.log(this.commitments);
  },
  error => {
    // always good practice to handle HTTP errors
  }
);
```

More details on how to access async data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely have to have `this.commitments` in your component, don't. It makes things more complicated, use the async pipe instead:

```
// component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-commitments',
  templateUrl: './commitments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./commitments.component.css']
})
export class CommitmentsComponent implements OnInit {
  commitments$ = this.commimentsService.getCommitments();
  constructor(private commitmentsService: CommitmentsService) { }
}

//template
<some-other-component [commitments]="commitments$ | async"></some-other-component>
```

By "it makes things more complicated" I mean you have a bunch of things to concern yourself with - managing subscriptions, making sure `this.commitments` is up to date when accessing it from inside your component.

I've developed in an application where a ton of instance variables were created per component, purely for the purpose of the pattern that you have written above. It gets unwieldly much faster than you think it does.